# Could anyone say if this is a reliable shuffling code?

Tags: c#, random

I am trying to prove the famous ["Monty Hall Paradox"](https://www.statisticshowto.com/probability-and-statistics/monty-hall-problem/):

> The Monty Hall problem is a probability puzzle named after **Monty Hall**, the original host of the TV show ***Let’s Make a Deal***. It’s a famous paradox that has a solution that is so absurd, most people refuse to believe it’s true.

```
private static void suffle(ulong numberOfTries)
    {
        int correctHits = 0;
        int wrongHits = 0;

        var prizeIndex = new Random();

        for (ulong i = 1; i <= numberOfTries; i++)
        {
            int[] doors = { 1, 2, 3 };

            var prizeDoor = doors[prizeIndex.Next(0, doors.Length)] ;

            var selectedDoor = doors[prizeIndex.Next(0, doors.Length)];               

            int discardedDoor = doors[prizeIndex.Next(0, doors.Length)];

            while (discardedDoor == prizeDoor || discardedDoor == selectedDoor)
            {
                discardedDoor = doors[prizeIndex.Next(0, doors.Length)];
            }

            var correctGuess = selectedDoor == prizeDoor;

            if (correctGuess) correctHits++;
            else wrongHits++;

            Console.WriteLine($"Prize Door: {prizeDoor}\nSelected Door: {selectedDoor}\nDiscarded Door: {discardedDoor}\nRight Guess? {correctGuess}\n\n");
        }

        Console.WriteLine($"Right Guesses: {correctHits} / {numberOfTries}\nWrong Guesses: {wrongHits} / {numberOfTries}");
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

your code is pretty neat and readable. Shuffling algorithm looks reliable to me, however I have a few comments to your C# code.

1. You pass the argument `numberOfTries` as `ulong` type, but `correctHits` and `wrongHits` are `int`. It could lead to wrong output if the `numberOfTries` is large enough to overflow `int.MaxValue`.
2. Variable doors are initialized in each loop. It could be initialized once in higher scope, e.g. before the `for` loop.
3. I can see repetetive code `doors[prizeIndex.Next(0, doors.Length)]`. This piece of code could be refactored to isolated method. For example:

   private static int GetDoorNumber() => _doors[_prizeIndex.Next(0, _doors.Length)];
4. You can save couple of code lines introducing ternary operator. Then you do not need variable correctGuess.

   correctHits += (selectedDoor == prizeDoor) ? 1 : 0;

You can calculate `wrongHits` as a difference of numberOfTries and correctHits. But your solution works too.